# Remove parent li text with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this html code:

```
<div class="menu">
    <p class="menutext">
        <li class="pagenav">test
            <ul>
                <li class="page_item page-item-190 current_page_item">
                    <a href="http://test.com/">test2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </p>
</div>
```

I will just remove `test` at this line:

```
<li class="pagenav">test
```

How I can do this with jquery?

Comment: You mean to remove `test`?

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: @xdazz sorry, typo error. Yes, I mean `test`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
var cachedChildren = $('.pagenav').children();
$('.pagenav').empty().append(cachedChildren);
```

This will cache all child DOM elements, empty the container and then append the cached DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap 'test' into a span like this

```
<li class="pagenav"><span class="mytext">test</span>
```

and the link to:

```
<a href="http://test.com/" class="update">test2</a>
```

you can then remove the test value by doing:

```
$('.update').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.pagenav').find('.mytext').empty();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('.pagenav').html($('.pagenav').children());
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Fy4mJ/

Answer (score 0):

Without touching the other elements in `.pagenav`, and just target the text, do :

```
$('.pagenav').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/XNbF9/)